# WinXP shared drives issue

Tags: .net, networking, windows-xp, shared, drives

I have an app in .NET that writes some really small files (2k-40k) on some network shared drives. These network shared drives are on another WinXP machine. The issue I'm having is that the app is able to write to the shared drive, but unable to open the same file using:

```
Process.Start(fullPathFileName);
```

The error I'm getting is "The system cannot find the file specified". By browsing the shared drive I can see the file being created and I can open it from WinExplorer without any issues. Any ideas ?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? It makes no sense to copy a small file to another XP machine, and then try to execute that file from the source machine. Are you expecting it to run on the remote machine? It won't - it wll execute on the source machine, meaning it will transfer back across the network into the RAM on the source system.

Comment: believe or not you can still find netAdmins that are recommending the usage of WinXP as a file server, so they store all their docs on a shared drive on one of the WinXP machines from their network, and open the files from this drive.

Comment: @user: Why are they recommending this, other than sheer ignorance? Windows XP was **never** recommended for use as a file server, and certainly wouldn't be anymore. You can share drives from modern versions of Windows, too. They haven't removed all of the useful features.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a security issue to me. I am sure that you have tried looking at the files permissions, but in case you have not... :)

Comment: Checked all securities and it seems ok (no Active Directory though)